# How to remove the tags

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I have my xml generated as below. How can i remove the Metadata and task tags? Please suggest.

```
<Metadata xmlns="uuid:4a83f382-8429-459c-ad3c-49b166dc611f"> 
<effective_date>2012-08-30T11:49:47</effective_date> 
<task xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="tcm:56-1746" xlink:title="Component"       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
</Metadata>
```

Comment: generated by who? You want it removed with which language/tool?

Comment: Does this mean you wanted to capture the effective_date value?